# Tengo un error de OAuth

Tags: oauth

Tengo este error a la hora de pedir autorización 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Requiero que me ayuden,

Comment: Esto pasa en tu aplicación o en qué contexto sucede?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, ¿podrías compartir al menos el lenguaje en el que desarrollas la aplicación, la URL y la configuración de los orígenes permitidos?

Answer (score 0):

Quería pedir autorización en Facebook desde la aplicación de Monarch en mi word press, pero me marcó este error al pedirla.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Esto quizá es una edición de tu pregunta más que una respuesta. [Pulsa aquí para editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/353746/edit) y agregar esta información adicional en ella.